# Godot: Is there a way to set custom import parameters for importing assets by code (C#)?

Tags: c#, game-development, game-engine, godot, godot4

During getting improvement to my custom import resource plugin I faced with need of set custom (re)importing params such as: compress mode (vram compressed or etc), channel pack (optimised or RGBFriendly). But I didn't find any clues in source classes or the documentation of Godot. How can I manually import file with setting import settings precisely?

I've tried looking through various of available import-named classes (EditorImportPlugin, EditorInterface, ResourceImporterTexture), but none of them could help me in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution. Godot IDE has according settings tab for picking import defaults.
[image]